# How can I backspace while writing to a text file using "cat > text.txt"?

Tags: linux, terminal, cat

Is there a way to use backspace when typing in to a text file through terminal using this command:

```
cat > text.txt
```

Or is there a better command to use other than `cat` to type into a txt file?

Comment: You could use here-docs, but what exactly is the problem? Could you explain more?

Comment: id like to use the terminal to be able to edit text i.e backspace/delete text using the cat command. I konw this is thwo differne proccessors but is there a way i can get the terminal window to act like a basic text editor?

Comment: Backspace should be working fine (before you press enter) due to the terminal's line buffering. Are you finding that this is not the case? What happens instead? Is it still a problem if you run `reset` first to reset your terminal settings?

Comment: Use a text editor like vim.

Comment: @that other guy : thanks yea i didnt know about line buffering it works before i press enter. Thanks perfect thanks.

Comment: And if you want to enter an explicit ^H, you can precede it with a ^V.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Whatever text incl.  special chars" > text file.txt
```

From comment you posted below your question you mention:

> is there a way i can get the terminal window to act like a basic text editor?

If that's what you want why not use vim/nano/emacs? There are plenty console text editors with surprising amount of advanced functionality in many cases (*quite often more than GUI editors*)

Answer (score 0):

If the [backspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace) key not working you could give a try to

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

but depends mainly on your terminal.